# HTML form post on port of a server, not URL

Tags: html, post, port

I have a device with Linux installed which will be configurable via a web page (a web server runs on this device). The configuration page is a simple HTML form:

```
<form method="post" action="http://192.168.0.120:9080">
    <!-- Some configuration options -->
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
```

As can be seen from `action="http://192.168.0.120:9080"`, I have a second server on this device that listens on port 9080. But I want to omit the IP address part (which will obviously change when connected to another network). Is there an option to do something like `action="http://this.server's.address:9080"`?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you specify a new port number, you must specify the hostname explicitly at the same time.

You can use a scheme-relative URL:

```
//192.168.0.120:9080
```

… but that is as close as you can get.

---

Consider generating the hostname portion dynamically with server side code.